# TorqTite BB for press fit creak?

Tags: creak, press-fit

I have that classic complaint, a creaking press fit bottom bracket. I like everything else about my set-up, so I'm stuck with press fit for now. Specifically the BB is a Praxis M30 with Zayante carbon cranks. It's a Fuji frame with PF30 (68x46) shell. I've isolated the creak to the BB with about 85% confidence. I was going to switch to Aldhu 3D+ cranks anyway because I can get a nice discount on them, so now is the time to switch out the BB too. My question: what is the press fit BB (that works with my set-up) that has the best chance of not creaking?

My regular mechanic tells me it's Enduro's TorqTite. Can you guys vouch for that or should I go with something different? Wheels Mfg? Kogel? Please don't say BBInfinite, I have a good budget but I can't go that high.

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

While product recommendations are off-topic here, there's a case to be made for sticking with the same manufacturer in a case like this where you can just also get the Rotor screw-together PF30 BB product ([plus the needed spacer configuration](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2338/5139/files/Aldhu_Spacers_chart.pdf?11320031558362409824)). The reason is that spindle OD to spindle contact ID tolerance is a piece of the puzzle when you're trying to eliminate creaks, and all else equal you're more likely to have that go wrong with a brand mismatch than a match.

Personally I'm ambivalent about the idea that anyone is executing the screw-together concept much better than anyone else. If you get any of the reasonable quality ones and it doesn't work, it's probably the frame's fault.

Answer (score 1):

Creaking BB is not a BB problem (usually), but a frame problem. You should check your frame if you BB hole diameter is within specifications, if hole is round and if left and right side hole centers are aligned. It's more common for carbon frames. Problems arise from that are creaking, higher rolling resistance, lower bearing service life. Minor cases can be alleviated by using pressfit BB whose cups are connected (by solid body or threaded together). Using BB that has plastic cups and inserts between BB bearing and crank axle (like shimano presfit BB) would also help solve some noise, but won't help with higher rolling resistance or lower brearing service life. Threaded BB's usually don't suffers these problems since threaded BBs don't thread directly into carbon, but into metal sleeve and making well aligned metal sleeve is easier for manufacturers.